# How to downgrade a Windows 10 application

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app

The Windows 10 Remote Desktop app (not "Remote Desktop Connection", the old terminal services client) has a bug (or perhaps a feature change) in the recent version (10.2.1234.0) that causes it to not play nicely with Remote Desktop Authentication certificates - it seems to require Server Authentication certificates.  Our server team may at some point change to using those certificates, but for the moment I'm stuck using the Remote Desktop Connection application.  The older version (10.1.1215.0) worked fine, and presumably would continue to do so.

Is there a way to downgrade the Remote Desktop application to the older version?  I'd love a "general" answer covering any Windows 10 app, but if the answer is specific to this app that's fine.  I'm assuming this is categorized as a Windows Store app, but it was installed by default on my local machine. I don't normally log on with administrative privileges, but do have an admin account if needed for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The remote desktop UWP app referred to in the question has been around for a while, initially as "Remote Desktop Preview", and now as "[Microsoft Remote Desktop](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/microsoft-remote-desktop/9wzdncrfj3ps?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)". The information in this answer applies equally to this app and to any Windows Store app.

When you obtain an app from the Windows Store, the version you receive is determined automatically by the Windows Store. This depends on various factors including the platform and OS version of the device you are using to connect to the Windows Store. There is no mechanism for choosing a version yourself.

In consequence, in the event of a problem with a particular version of an app, the only way for users to receive a different version is for the app publisher to submit a new version to the Windows Store. Once the new version has completed the registration process, it becomes available for users, and all existing users with a lower version number receive the update.

There is information about it [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/package-version-numbering).

Comment: Your answer in one word: no, you can't downgrade it.

Comment: @meblum that's 5 words